# replace contents of NSMutableAttributedString after appended

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsmutableattributedstring

I want to change a contents of `NSMutableAttributedString` object which was already appended to anonter `NSMutableAttributedString` (which is displayed in `UITextView`).
The following code did not updating text on the screen:

```
var my_text = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "")
my_text_view.attributedText = my_text

let ats = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: ":"+sml+":", attributes: [.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16),.foregroundColor:UIColor.gray])
my_text.append(ats)
my_text_view.attributedText = my_text // this refreshes all attachments

...

ats.mutableString.setString("") // The text on the screen did not changed
my_text_view.attributedText = my_text //  Still no changes
```

All of the image attachments are updating, so this is not an UITextView issue.
So, how to update a text in `NSMutableAttributedString`?

Comment: I suggest instead of updating the existing mutable string, just create a new one.

Comment: First change your my_text attributed string then set it to your text view

Comment: When you append `ats` to `my_text`, it just copies the data.  It doesn't keep a *live copy* of `ats`, so modifying `ats` after the fact has no further effect on `my_text`.